# Just need a tiny code rephrasing about range()

Tags: python, range

So here's the code that i have been currently working on, but my boss isn't quite happy about the last part of it. can someone help me? the problem below is marked. thanks in advance!

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def codeNameDict(lst, cnDict):
    key = int(lst[0])
    value = lst[1]
    cnDict[key] = value
    return cnDict

def realNameDict(lst, rnDict):
    key = int(lst[0])
    value = lst[2].strip()
    rnDict[key] = value
    return rnDict

def getCodeKey(keys):
    import random
    index = random.choice(keys)
    return index

def searchKey(cnDict,value):
    for x in cnDict.keys():
      if(value == cnDict.get(x)):
        return x
        break;

def namegen(cnDict):
    index1 = getCodeKey(cnDict.keys())
    index2 = getCodeKey(cnDict.keys())

    if(index1 == index2):
     while(index1 == index2):
      index2 = getCodeKey(cnDict.keys())
      indexgen = [index1,index2]

    else:
      indexgen = [index1,index2]
    return indexgen

cnDict = {}
rnDict = {}

f = open("namefile.txt")
try:
    for line in f:
        words = line.split(":")
        cnDict = codeNameDict(words,cnDict)
        rnDict = realNameDict(words,rnDict)
finally:
    f.close()


# PROBLEMATIC SECTION #
for x in range(10):
    indexgen = namegen(cnDict)
    key1 = indexgen[0]
    key2 = indexgen[1]
    #print indexgen
    #print key1
    #print key2
    pokemon1 = cnDict[key1]
    pokemon2 = cnDict[key2]
    realname1 = rnDict[key1]
    realname2 = rnDict[key2]

    print "Partners-> %s:%s" % (pokemon1, pokemon2)
    print "RealNames-> %s:%s" % (realname1, realname2)

    del cnDict[key1]
    del cnDict[key2]
```

Comment: Seriously broken formatting. :|

Comment: Why is your boss not happy with it?

Comment: Maybe it's because of the *magic value* `10` in `range(10)`?

Comment: think he wants it simpler. i just started learning python :|

Comment: @caughtdaydreaming You can make the lines `key1 = indexgen[0]\nkey2 = indexgen[1]` to one: `key1, key2 = indexgen[0], indexgen[1]`. The same with pokemon and realname.

Comment: I'll make it an answer for you to accept if you are satisfied with it ok:)

Comment: I hate it too, when my boss makes me do pokemon-related stuff in programming language i don't know well :(

Comment: @halex alrighty then! :)

Comment: @wasyl aww. we seem to be on the same page. :(

Comment: @caughtdaydreaming I see you're new, so FYI - consider accepting best answer and upvoting answers that solved your problem or were useful. More here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I think you ought to post [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for this kind of questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the lines

```
key1 = indexgen[0]
key2 = indexgen[1]
```

to one with:

```
key1, key2 = indexgen[0], indexgen[1].
```

The same with `pokemon1, pokemon2`  and `realname1, realname2`.
I also would not use the magic value `10` but give it a name.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple improvements to your code. Let's take for example:

```
def getCodeKey(keys):
import random
index = random.choice(keys)
return index
```

This is effectively returning what `random.choice` would return. I'd suggest moving `import` statement to the beginning of the file, and using `random.choice` instead of `getCodeKey` (for, again, it's the same thing)

Secondly, in `searchKey`, there's no need to `break` after return, as return already returns from function. However, you should consider some action if searched value *is not* in the dictionary...

Third,

```
if(index1 == index2):
 while(index1 == index2):
  index2 = getCodeKey(cnDict.keys())
  indexgen = [index1,index2]

else:
  indexgen = [index1,index2]
return indexgen
```

`if` is not necessary, for if it's not true, `while` loop won't be executed. Then you don't need `else` as well, notice that you're setting value to indexgen bot in `if` and `else` statement. Also - it's not necessary to create variable for a value that you're gonna return immediately anyway. I'd rewrite it to

```
 while(index1 == index2):
  index2 = getCodeKey(cnDict.keys())

return [index1,index2]
```

As for the `range` part, the only I see would be what *halex* suggested, namely putting all double statements into one line.

```
key1, key2 = indexgen[0], indexgen[1]
```

I don't think that changes much, though...

That's not exactly what you asked for, but as you stated - you're learning python, so I think this might be at least a little useful